# Is it possible to obtain data for signal b when signal a reaches this point?

Tags: python

I'm very new to python, but if I have an ECG signal, is it possible to obtain the data point for signal b (that may look like a sine wave) when the ECG signal reaches end-systole or end-diastole? As in have the ECG trigger the reading for signal b?

I have given examples of an ECG signal and signal_b, but not sure how to do this.

```
ECG = [ -0.011, -0.015, -0.017, -0.010, -0.017, -0.015, -0.017, -0.014, -0.017, -0.017, -0.018, -0.018, -0.021, -0.019, -0.015, -0.023, -0.022, -0.020, -0.019, -0.019, -0.017, -0.017, -0.019, -0.020, -0.013, -0.014, -0.015, -0.013, -0.011, -0.014, -0.015, -0.012, -0.013, -0.013, -0.015, -0.011, -0.019, -0.019, -0.016, -0.018, -0.018, -0.013, -0.015, -0.015, -0.016, -0.011, -0.017, -0.018, -0.013, -0.016, -0.018, -0.018, -0.016, -0.020, -0.019, -0.018, -0.018, -0.019, -0.019, -0.016, -0.018, -0.017, -0.012, -0.013, -0.014, -0.011, -0.011, -0.013, -0.017, -0.011, -0.013, -0.012, -0.012, -0.007, -0.014, -0.009, -0.005, -0.007, -0.003, 0.000, 0.002, 0.004, 0.008, 0.014, 0.014, 0.016, 0.023, 0.024, 0.027, 0.030, 0.036, 0.035, 0.036, 0.042, 0.042, 0.043, 0.045, 0.049, 0.048, 0.050, 0.052, 0.053, 0.052, 0.055]

signal_b = [
    0.971, 0.969, 0.970, 0.967, 0.965, 0.966, 0.970, 0.969, 0.971, 0.968, 0.963, 0.964, 0.965,
    0.967, 0.967, 0.964, 0.964, 0.961, 0.962, 0.960, 0.967, 0.965, 0.964, 0.962, 0.961, 0.963,
    0.962, 0.962, 0.965, 0.962, 0.958, 0.958, 0.960, 0.961, 0.959, 0.959, 0.956, 0.956, 0.956,
    0.956, 0.958, 0.959, 0.957, 0.954, 0.951, 0.954, 0.957, 0.957, 0.955, 0.948, 0.948, 0.950,
    0.950, 0.950, 0.951, 0.951, 0.945, 0.943, 0.943, 0.947, 0.949, 0.948, 0.941, 0.940, 0.938,
    0.942, 0.944, 0.946, 0.944, 0.940, 0.936, 0.937, 0.939, 0.940, 0.938, 0.938, 0.936, 0.931,
    0.930, 0.927, 0.936, 0.935, 0.935, 0.928, 0.928, 0.930, 0.930, 0.934, 0.931, 0.927, 0.925,
    0.920, 0.928, 0.928, 0.926, 0.925, 0.920, 0.918, 0.920, 0.921, 0.922, 0.922, 0.919, 0.915,
    0.914, 0.918, 0.917, 0.917, 0.917, 0.912, 0.910, 0.909, 0.910, 0.913, 0.910, 0.907, 0.906,
    0.905, 0.902, 0.906, 0.908, 0.906, 0.904, 0.903, 0.899, 0.903, 0.902, 0.900, 0.900, 0.896,
    0.894, 0.897, 0.896, 0.897, 0.895, 0.894, 0.890, 0.891, 0.889]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, sharex=True)
ax[0].plot(ECG)
ax[1].plot(signal_b)
plt.show()
```

Comment: _"Don't ask about...

    Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)"_ [tour] You could loop over the first signal, find the index and use the index for the second signal.

Comment: how do you determine in the `ECG` series the point of interest that you are looking for? Also, the two arrays don't have the same length; why is that? Are the implicit time indices at the same resolution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are ambiguities in the question. What is the criterion on the ECG series that indicates the point of interest?  Why are the two arrays of different length (that makes me suspicious that perhaps they are not captured at the same time resolution)?

If the intent is to identify where `ESG` becomes non-negative (i.e. literally the first ESG sample that is greater or equal to 0), and then take `signal_b` from that index and on, here is how to do it. Happy to change the answer if more details come through.

```py
import numpy as np


idx0 = np.where(np.array(ECG) >= 0)[0][0]
b_plus = signal_b[idx0:]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, sharex=True)
ax[0].plot(ECG)
ax[0].axhline(0)
ax[0].axvline(idx0)
ax[1].plot(signal_b)
# red point: start of b where ESG >= 0
ax[1].plot(idx0, signal_b[idx0], 'ro')
# red line: b_plus
ax[1].plot(np.arange(idx0, len(signal_b)), b_plus, 'r')
plt.show()
```

[image]